# Why does File.Exists test not work on either Windows or Andoird in C# .net MAUI App?

Tags: c#, maui

**This is an edit of my original question.**

I have a C# .Net MAUI App that checks for the existence of a source file (the standard `Project/Resources/Raw/AboutAssets.txt` file) during the `OnAppearing()` event.

[image: AboutAssets.txt in Raw Resources folder]

**My question is why does this `File.Exists` test not work on either Windows or Android?**

---

My Code

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SourceFileExists2;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Debug.WriteLine($"APP DATA DIRECTORY = {FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory}");

        string sourceFile = "AboutAssets.txt";
        Debug.WriteLine($"SOURCE FILE = {sourceFile}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"FILE EXISTS 1 = {File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, sourceFile))}");

        string sourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, sourceFile);
        Debug.WriteLine($"SOURCE PATH = {sourcePath}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"FILE EXISTS 2 = {File.Exists(sourcePath)}");
    }
}
```

Windows Output

```
APP DATA DIRECTORY = C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Packages\fd35e565-25c7-4731-bfd1-6267e4eafe80_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState
SOURCE FILE = AboutAssets.txt
FILE EXISTS 1 = False
SOURCE PATH = C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Packages\fd35e565-25c7-4731-bfd1-6267e4eafe80_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState\AboutAssets.txt
FILE EXISTS 2 = False
```

Android Output

```
[0:] APP DATA DIRECTORY = /data/user/0/com.companyname.sourcefileexists2/files
[0:] SOURCE FILE = AboutAssets.txt
[0:] FILE EXISTS 1 = False
[0:] SOURCE PATH = /data/user/0/com.companyname.sourcefileexists2/files/AboutAssets.txt
[0:] FILE EXISTS 2 = False
```

**Why does the file existence test not work on either Windows or Android?**

Comment: what is the build action of `AboutAssets.txt`?

Comment: @Jason I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "build action", but in this very simple example, it doesn't really do anything. This stems from a more complex program I'm writing in which a database is copied and then used in SQLite - that exhibits the exact same problem - so I tried to isolate the problem here with a simple example.  Am I missing something?  Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022

Comment: Thanks for the useful link!  I see ```Build Action = MauiAsset```.  And now I also see the Full Path, which makes perfect sense: ```E:\Documents\MAUI\SourceFileExistsDemo\SourceFileExistsDemo\Resources\Raw\AboutAssets.txt```.  I'll try using this.

Comment: This fixed it" ```string sourceFolder = "E:\\Documents\\MAUI\\SourceFileExistsDemo\\SourceFileExistsDemo\\Resources\\Raw\\";
        string sourceFile = "AboutAssets.txt";
        string fullSource = Path.Combine( sourceFolder, sourceFile );
        if (File.Exists(fullSource))``` - please post as an answer, if you'd like!

Comment: I don't think that logic will work with iOS/Android or even Windows when the app is deployed.  Why do you need to do this?  What is the scenario where an asset bundled with your app is suddenly missing at runtime?

Comment: a more reliable solution might be to use a relative path of `Resources\Raw`, but even then I'm not sure why you would need this

Comment: That's a good point.  Perhaps this isn't necessary.  The reason I was doing it is because the resource file is essential and it just seemed like a good idea to check for it, but perhaps that doesn't make sense beyond development.

Comment: I assume that `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` will fail or return null if the file is not there

Comment: And the file is present on the Android device? Are you sure about it?  `/data/user/0/com.companyname.sourcefileexistsdemo/files/AboutAssets.txt`

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I thought it did, but just to be sure, I started a new project to eliminate any chance that past activities "polluted" my program.  Now I realize it doesn't work on either OS because the ```AboutAssets.txt``` file is not in the ```AppDataDirectory```.

Comment: Well if you don't create the file, it would not be there. That is why the original example was talking about "running the application twice, where 1st run would create the file and second not find it". I assume the issue is resolved then? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-7.0), `System.IO.File.Exists()` takes an argument `path`:

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see `GetCurrentDirectory`.

If you would run from the code method `System.IO.File.GetCurrentDirectory`, it will point possible to different directory than the result of `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory` (which you are using for saving).

To resolve this, you must combine and check the correct path:

```cs
string sourceFile = "AboutAssets.txt";
string sourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, sourceFile);

if (File.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    // ...
}
```

---

The main takeaway is that there are 2 directories in MAUI approach:

- Directory with application (with *.exe)

  - stores the application executable + general config files
  - methods pointing to directory with exes:

    - `System.IO.File.GetCurrentDirectory`
    - `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
    - `AppContext.BaseDirectory`
  - e.g.: `C:\MyApp\myApp.exe`
- Directory with data per platform

  - stores the application data + user specific configs
  - methods pointing to directory with "data-store" purpose:

    - `FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory` (MAUI helper path)
    - `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` (native)
  - e.g.: `C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Packages\e1db9eee-54c8-48a0-8472-d7fda39ef4ed_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState`

Comment: I tried the directories, but couldn't get it to work.  Perhaps I'm too dense to understand what you mean, so let me be more specific: (1) I'm primarily trying to get this to work on Android.  (2) When successfully deploy my app, ```AboutAssets.txt``` ends up at ```data/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/AboutAssets.txt```.  (3) So he question is where is the source during deployment?  Is it at ```data/user/0/com.mydomain.myapp/files/AboutAssets.txt```?  If so, how do I check that?

Comment: You are running code `File.Exists(sourceFile)`, instead try this `File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, sourceFile))`. Is this clearer?

Comment: Yes, ```AppDataDirectory``` seems right, because it equates to ```/data/user/0/com.companyname.sourcefileexistsdemo/files/AboutAssets.txt``` and when I go there using an emulator file explorer, I see the file! However ```Debug.WriteLine($"FILE TEST = {File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, sourceFile))}");``` always returns ```FILE TEST = False``` and I have no idea why!

Comment: @SqueezeOJ Could you update your question with all those details / rework the question? This is completely different issue than the one described (as in the original question it is clear that you are calling `File.Exists` with wrong argument ).

Comment: Good idea - I just rewrote the question and code to reflect the fact that my code works on Windows, but not Android.  I didn't realize this entirely before.